# Long duration soak tests in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

Jmeter tests are run in master slave fashion with around 8 slave machines. However with the remote batching mode set to MODE_STRIPPED_BATCH, I am not able to run tests for more than 64 hours. Throughput is around 450 requests per minute, and per slave machine it results in the creation of jtl files that are around 1.5 gb. All 8 slaves are going to send this to the master (1.5 gb x 8) and probably the I/O gets too much for the master to handle. The master machines memory is at 16 gb ram and has disk storage of around 250 gb. I was wondering if the jmeter distributed architecture has any provision to make long running soak tests possible without any un explained stress on the master machine. Obviously I have the option to abandon master slave setup and go for 8 independent nodes, however I'll in that case run into complications with respect to serving data csv files ( which I currently serve using simple table server plugin from the master m) and also around aggregating result files. Any suggestions please. It would be great to be able to run tests atleast for around 4 days (96 hours or so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go for an independent JMeter workers + external data collector setup.

Actually, the JMeter right-out-of-the-box "distributed scaling" abilities are weak, way outdated & overall pretty ridiculous. As well as it's data collection/agregation/processing abilities.

This situation actually puzzles me a lot - mind you, rivals are even worse, so there's literally NOTHING in the field (except for, perhaps, some SaaS solutions trying to monetize on this gap).
But is is what it is...

So that's about *why*-s, now to *how*-s.

If I were you, I would:

1. Containerize the JMeter worker
2. Equip each container with a watchdog to quickly restart the worker if things go south locally (or probably even on schedule to refresh it ultimately). Be that an internal one, or external like cloud services have - doesn't matter.
3. Set up a timeseries database - I recommend InfluxDB, it's an excellent product & it's free in basic version (which is going to be enough for your purposes).
4. Flow your test results/metrics into that DB - do not collect them locally! You can do it right from your tests with pretty simple custom listener (Influx line protocol is ridiculously simple & fast), or you can have external agent watching the result files as they flow. I just suggest you not to use so called Backend Listner to do the job - it's garbage, it won't shape your data right, so you'd have to do additional ops to bring them to order.
5. If you shape your test result/metrics data properly, you've get 'em already time-synced into a single set - and the further processing options are amazingly powerful!

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you're looking for the `StrippedAsynch` sampler sender mode.

As per the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode):

> **Asynch**
>
> samples are temporarily stored in a local queue. A separate worker thread sends the samples. This allows the test thread to continue without waiting for the result to be sent back to the client. However, if samples are being created faster than they can be sent, the queue will eventually fill up, and the sampler thread will block until some samples can be drained from the queue. This mode is useful for smoothing out peaks in sample generation. The queue size can be adjusted by setting the JMeter property `asynch.batch.queue.size` (default `100`) on the server node.
>
> **StrippedAsynch**
>
> remove responseData from successful samples, and use Async sender to send them.

So on slave node add the following line to *user.properties* file:

```
mode=StrippedAsynch
```

and on the master node define `asynch.batch.queue.size`, to be as high to not to have impact onto JMeter's throughput (won't slow it down) and as low to not to overwhelm the master. I would start with `1000`.

Another option is using `StrippedDiskStore` but you will have to manually collect serialized results after test completion (make sure that slave processes will not shut down because the results will be deleted when slave process finishes)

You could use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) to monitor memory and network usage on master and slaves.

Comment: Thanks. Attempted specifying StrippedDiskStore, however am noticing that the results are still sent to the master at the end of the test. Exact commands am using are:
To run the client .  
`jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl -R<serverip>`

To run the server:
`jmeter-server -n -t -Dserver.rmi.localport=4000 -Dserver_port=1099 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/jmeter_server_results`

Comment: Jmeter version that i am on is 5.1.1

Comment: Sorry to come back on this one @dmitri-t. Do you know if there is a way to prevent slaves from sending the result to the master?